# Can i update in many to many field django

Tags: python-2.7, django-models

I want to update manytomany field, the others answers say than first remove and later add, but I need to know if is possible only update, may model:

```
class CtlgTypeExercise(models.Model):
    type_exercise = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class CtlgExercise(models.Model):
    exercise = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    time = models.IntegerField()
    ctlg_type_exercise = models.ForeignKey('CtlgTypeExercise')

class UsrExercisePlan(models.Model):
    user = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    date = models.DateField()
    ctlg_exercise = models.ManyToManyField('CtlgExercise')
```

In CtlgTypeExercise has: Run, Swim, Bicycle .....

In CtlgExercise has: "Run 20 minutes in the street"  and type is "Run", or "Run 10 minutes in the mountain", type "Run", or "Swim 30 minutes" type "Swim".....

In UsrExercisePlan save the user and exercise, for example user:"Peter", date:"Today", ctlg_exercise:"Run 20 minutes in the street" well the id. Now I want to replace or update ctlg_exercise per "Swim 30 minutes".

What is the best way to update, I dont want to remove and add, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, if you write:

```
usrExe = UsrExercisePlan.objects.get(user__id=idUser)
usrExe.ctlg_exercise = [newExercise]
```

automatically remove and add new Object, but I don't know with the id field, because it is increasing. Somebody know what happen with Django and longs id fields autoincrement, maybe django reset id field?